# Solving the equation $x' + \frac{x}{t} = t^2x^4$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried solving $x' + \frac{x}{t} = t^2x^4$ by substituting $z = \frac{1}{x^3} $but I cant seem to solve the equation I get. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This might be helpful - http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Bernoulli.aspx

Comment: The method described requires the coefficient of $z'$ to be 1. I'm not sure how to solve the equation $z' + \frac{-3}{tz} = -3t^2$

Comment: My mistake, your link helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start substituting $$x=\frac{1}{z^{\frac13}}$$ you have $$x'=-\frac{z'}{3 z^{4/3}}$$ and then $$x' + \frac{x}{t} - t^2x^4=0$$ becomes, after simplifications $$-\frac{3 t^3+t z'-3 z}{3 t z^{4/3}}=0$$ which means that you have to solve $$3z-tz'=3 t^3$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

I should add that there is a very close change of variable which leads to a very simple equation; I let you finding it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the LHS is "almost" $(tx)'=tx'+x$ hence the equation is equivalent to $$\frac{(tx)'}{(tx)^4}=\frac1t.$$ Can you proceed from there?